# How can I drop console in a VITE2 project?

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I tried to drop console for my Vite2 project. I googled and found the terserOptions, however, it didn't work. So I just create a blank template from the offical site with the following code.

```
yarn create vite my-vue-app --template vue
```

And then add some console.log on Helloworld page.
the vite.config.js is below:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";


export default defineConfig({
  base: "./",
  plugins: [vue()],
  bulid: {
    terserOptions: {
      compress: {
        drop_console: true,
        drop_debugger: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

After I build the project, the console.log still there. So what's the right way to drop_console on a project built by vite2?

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify in [`build.minify`](https://vitejs.dev/config/#build-minify) to use `terser`.

If not set, `terserOptions` is ignored as it defaults to using `esbuild`.

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";


export default defineConfig({
  base: "./",
  plugins: [vue()],
  bulid: {
    minify: 'terser', // <-- add
    terserOptions: {
      compress: {
        drop_console: true,
        drop_debugger: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

This setting removes `console.*` at **build time**.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `esbuild`, you can use this:

```
 esbuild: {
  drop: ['console', 'debugger'],
 }
```